# Inkscape: Cut an unfilled rectangle into four sides

Tags: inkscape

I have not found an answer to this, although I am perhaps searching for the wrong terms ...

Ink Inkscape, I'd like to change an unfilled rectangle into its four separate sides. I thought that if I select the rectangle and use `Path -> Object to Path`, I would then be able to "snip" the rectangle at it's four corners, but I have not been able to do that. An alternative approach, but one I have also not managed to achieve, would be to select just a single side of the rectangle, and then copy it and paste it back.

How can I best achieve my aim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After converting the rectangle to path

- select the path
- select all corner nodes by dragging around with the node tool
- apply infobar option "Break path at selected nodes"
- apply Path > Break Apart

The last one probably is the one you didn't know. Breaking a path at selected nodes does the breaking, but the result is a combined path made of 4 parts.

If you continue using Inkscape you'll see that you must by yourself combine paths quite often and common functions generate them without asking (as you have already seen). Filled areas with holes are combined paths. Path effects often need combined paths instead of groups.

Comment: Many thanks. In fact, I failed on the last two steps!